# IText How to adjust pdf on page

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext

Is there a way to micro-adjust exactly where a PDF prints on a page within IText?

Here's my problem: It appears that naturally through variations in printer manufactures or age of printer, etc., minor variations occur when printing a PDF document. These variations are typically very small, however for 2 sample printers (both laser and the same model and manufacturer) the variation in text placement is upwards of 1-2 millimeters between printers. This would be fine for most normal printing however, for this task, this is outside of acceptable tolerances.

My gut reaction to this is to provide some ability to make micro adjustments to exactly where the print happens and thus be able to account for any variation within the printers themselves. Printing does appear to be consistent for all jobs sent to a single printer however.

Presently I have a PDF created in Adobe Acrobat Pro X that has form fields, that are then filled out by a java application and sent to the printer.

Thank you for any and all suggestions

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt to solve this issue would be to try changing the default settings of the printer driver... somehow.  But I can't give any useful pointers about that.

If you want to adjust the PDFs, you should probably change the page boundaries to shift the content.  For example, this code shifts the content of the first page 50 units down, for a simple PDF that has only a MediaBox.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("in.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"));
PdfDictionary pagedict = reader.getPageN(1);
PdfArray mediabox = pagedict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
mediabox.set(1, new PdfNumber(mediabox.getAsNumber(1).intValue()+50));
mediabox.set(3, new PdfNumber(mediabox.getAsNumber(3).intValue()+50));
stamper.close();
```

You'll have to adjust any other boxes (CropBox, BleedBox, etc) accordingly.  Take a look at the PDF spec for information on the different page boundaries.